# MyBatis do a fetch and based on return value do an update/insert inside the Xxxmapper.xml?

Tags: java, sql, database, mybatis

Is there a way to embed a `select from table` inside a Mybatis Insert SQL config, Which checks if the record is existing -> Runs the Update on the same table
else just inserts the data.
I know it can be done programtically but need a way to do it in the mapper.xml

Database: Oracle 11g, mybatis 3.1.x

Any suggestions are helpful

thanks

Comment: ANy suggestions, Also is there a tool to generate mybatis Mapper.xml from Java POJO ?.

Answer (score 2):

Use **UPSERT** statement, most of the database support **UPSERT** statements. the return value would be number of records updated or inserted. Though You have not provided the database against which you have performing the update or insert operation.

**UPDATE**

Oracle 11g does support upsert

```
MERGE INTO KP_TBL USING DUAL ON (MY_KEY= #{myKey}) 
        WHEN MATCHED THEN 
                UPDATE SET OTHER_PARAM = #{myOtherParam},
                           SEC_PARAM = #{sec_param}
        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
                INSERT (MY_KEY, OTHER_PARAM,SEC_PARAM)  VALUES(#{myKey},#{myOtherParam},#{sec_param)
```

Comment: @KP The db is Oracle DB 11g.

Comment: Oracle doesn't support an upsert statement so guess no out of the box solution here for me, got to move to PL/SQL etc...

Comment: @KP thanks for that Also wondering can I do a delete Insert in mybastis for oracle as well ?.

Comment: @SHinny I don't understand why you need delete insert. Delete insert is nothing but update

Comment: I get updates and sometime the rows received may be less or more then the previous update,
I donot want to keep stale data, So want to delete and load again.
If i only update and rows received are less i keep data which is no longer needed....

Comment: More Info, The data comes in via a JMS subscription so for the key I may have one or multiple rows of data varying over multiple JMS messages. I only want to keep latest records and remove old ones.

Comment: You need to reconsider your approach you need to explictly send the request for delete or consider mechanism similar to caching, where you specify data to live

Answer (score 0):

This could be done using means of SQL. Unfortunately you didn't mention which particular database management systen you use as there is no such feature in ANSI SQL.
For example if you use MySQL [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) is the way to go.

E.g.:

```
<insert id="instSample" parameterType="SampleModel">
   INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (#{a}, #{b}, #{c})
   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c = #{c};
</insert>
```

Comment: The db is Oracle DB 11g